# asp.net bitmap image blur, how to apply blur effect on a image from class

Tags: asp.net, blur

Can anyone direct me to some source / article where I can find information on how to apply blur effect on a bitmap / photo

I'm using following but it's not good !

```
    Dim oGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(oBitmap)
    Dim att As New ImageAttributes  'declare an ImageAttributes to use it when drawing'
    Dim m As New ColorMatrix  'declare a ColorMatrix'
    m.Matrix33 = 0.5 ' set Matrix33 to 0.5, which represents the opacity. so the drawing will be semi-trasparent.
    att.SetColorMatrix(m)   'Setting this ColorMatrix to the ImageAttributes.'
    For x = -1 To BlurSize  'drawing the image on it self, but not in the same coordinates, in a way that every pixel will be drawn on the pixels arround it.'
        For y = -1 To BlurSize
            oGraphics.DrawImage(imagePhoto, New Rectangle(x, y, imagePhoto.Width, imagePhoto.Height), 0, 0, imagePhoto.Width, imagePhoto.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, att) 'Drawing image on it self using out ImageAttributes to draw it semi-transparent.'
        Next
    Next
```

Regards

Comment: not good how, exactly? Describe your problem clearly. P.S. Asking for recommendations of 3rd-party resources or info is considered off-topic here - it may attract commercial spam or purely opinion-based response. Also, you can do your own research. Instead describe the issue clearly and what you have tried to do in order to solve it so far.

Comment: above code simply redrawing the same image on itself it's not creating blur... and I'm looking for some piece of code to apply blur effect on bitmap